# How to check if External Tables (PolyBase objects) are supported on given SQL Server using just SQL query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, polybase

This may as well be named "How to check if PolyBase is installed on SQL Server using just SQL Query" (as those two are basically synonyms).

When PolyBase is not installed, you're not able to call `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE`, `DATA SOURCE` or `FILE FORMAT`, etc.

**How can you check beforehand if those server features are available, using just SQL Query?**

**Is there anything like `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('IsPolyBaseInstalled')` for PolyBase component?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find some information with :

```
SELECT * 
FROM   sys.configurations 
WHERE  name LIKE '%polybase%' COLLATE French_CI_AI;
```

To enable PolyBase use sp_configure

Comment: Nice. Will mark this as an answer, as it was enough to figure out the rest. The exact name of the config is 'polybase enabled'.

Small note though: on some servers (e.g. MSSQLLocalDB) there's no such an entry, so the query I had in mind could look like this:

`SELECT ISNULL((SELECT value FROM sys.configurations WHERE name = 'polybase enabled'), 0) AS is_polybase_available`